# How to get Exact Time format using select query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I'm using below query to get the time as AM/PM format
eg:-
   if time is 2011-10-10 13:10:10 in database it will return  as
   1:10 PM

I just want to fetch like 01:10 PM

I used below query to fetch the above result

```
  SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT (varchar,FromDateTime,100),13,7)+' - '+SUBSTRING(CONVERT                             
  (varchar,ToDateTime,100),13,7) as EventTime FROM tblEvent
```

How to get the time time like 01:10 AM

Comment: Are you looking to pad your result on the left with zeros so that it's always the same length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert the datetime value using the default format, then extract the time portion and slightly modify it to guarantee the leading zero's presence when it's needed:

```
SELECT RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE()), 7)), 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can directly use convert with 108 as parameter

see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)